# Pass parameters to base.html from every single views

Tags: django

I have such a top nav-bar in the base.html

```
<div class='section-topbar'>
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="col-md-12">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
        {% for sec in sections %} {% if sec == current_section %}
        <li class="active">
          <a href="/article/list/{{ current_section.id }}">{{ current_section.name }}</a>
        </li>
        {% else %}
        <li>
          <a href="/article/list/{{ sec.id }}">{{ sec.name }}</a>
        </li>
        {% endif %} {% endfor %}
        <br class="cbt">
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div> <!--first row-->
</div>
```

It is designed to present on every single page, and retrieve two contextual parameter `sections` and `current_section` from the view,

```
context = {"page":page,
           "current_section": section,
           "sections": sections,}
return render(request, "article/article_list.html", context)
```

So I have to pass the extra parameters to templates from every views,

Is it possible to pass them in one go and enable them globally?

Comment: Is the section related to for example the app where the view is stored?

Comment: the section is a model table in database @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: yes, but how do you determine what the `current_section` is. Is there any (simple) logic behind this?

Comment: thanks for your inspiration, I got the idea, the current_section should be passed in to each template to determine which one is active. I am going to write a general function to retrieve data and update context. @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write your own `context_processor` which will inject the given variables in every view's context and they will be available in every template.

```
# myproject/myapp/context_processors.py

def sections_processor(request):
    # do something ...
    # then return your variables
    return {'sections': sections, 'current_section': section}
```

You'll need to register this context processor in your settings file so that Django will run it:

```
# myproject/myproject/settings.py

TEMPLATES = [{
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            ...
            'myappp.context_processors.sections_processor',
        ]
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is, you can use context_processors, so every template yours will have by default this variable loaded... but keep in mind all your pages must be able to run the code inside your context_processor

https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.0/_modules/django/template/context_processors/

**EDIT**: Here some code so you can try this out

settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',        
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [                
            ...
            'youapp.context_processors.yourcontextname_context_processor',
        ],
    },
}]
```

context_processors.py # Create it inside your app

```
def yourcontextname_context_processor(request):
    ... # Your logic        
    data = {
        'something': "something",
        'another_thing': "another_thing",
        'array_of_thing': ["thing", "thing", "thing", ],
    }

    return data
```

in your html

```
{{ something }}
{{ another_thing }}
{% for thing in array_of_thing %}
    {{ thing }}
{% endfor %}
```